# How to get a law of large numbers?

Tags: probability, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

I have a continuous-time stochastic process $X=\left(X_{t}\right)_{t \geq 0}$ for which I showed that there is $v>0$ such that, for integer times,

$$\frac{X_n}{n} \to v, \,\, \text{ $\mathbb{P}-a.s.$}$$

I can also show that
\begin{eqnarray}\label{1}
\mathbb{P}\left(|X_{t}-X_{\lfloor t \rfloor}|\geq\epsilon t\right) \leq \alpha e^{-\beta t}, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ (1)
\end{eqnarray}
for every $\epsilon > 0$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants that depend on $\epsilon$.

I want to show that

$$\frac{X_t}{t} \to v, \,\, \text{ $\mathbb{P}-a.s.$}$$

For this, I thought of writing the following:

$$\frac{X_{t}}{t}=\frac{X_{t}-X_{\lfloor t \rfloor}+X_{\lfloor t \rfloor}}{t}=\frac{X_{t}-X_{\lfloor t \rfloor}}{t}+ \frac{X_{\lfloor t \rfloor}}{t}.$$

But if I use Inequality $(1)$ I am going to get convergence in probability to $0$ for the first term on the right side, which does not imply almost surely convergence. Also, the second term should be divided by $\lfloor t \rfloor $ and not by $t$. Does anyone know a standard way of procedure in this case?

Comment: Sufficiently fast convergence in probability implies a.s. convergence, by the Borel-Cantelli lemma. The requirement is that the probabilities of deviations larger than $\varepsilon$ are summable for any $\varepsilon>0$. As for the other term, you can write $\frac{X_{\lfloor t \rfloor}}{t}=X_{\lfloor t \rfloor} \left ( \frac{1}{\lfloor t \rfloor} + \frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{\lfloor t \rfloor} \right )$ and then $\left | \frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{\lfloor t \rfloor} \right | \leq \frac{1}{\lfloor t \rfloor^2}$...

Comment: Thank you for your help, Ian.